# Why html panel in firebug losses focus

Tags: html, focus, firebug

As I try to modify content in the html panel in firebug the focus goes elsewhere and I have to click & type very quickly before it goes again.

If I press break on mutate, the focus does not wander, but then it breaks on mutate...

Is there an option I have enabled that is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue too.  On the HTML tab there is a drop-down arrow.  Click on it and unselect the option, "Scroll Changes Into View".  If you are on a webpage that actively tracks the mouse or has constant javascript going on, it is very likely that this is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about an option but it sounds like some script is writing to the page and interfering with your ability to edit. But checking that, my firebug lets me edit even the field that is being modified.

This is Firebug 1.8.4 on firefox 8

```
<!doctype HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        setInterval(function(){
          $('body').addClass('xx'+Math.floor(Math.random()*100));
        },2000);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```